# How are string objects stored in memory and why would one want to convert a string object into bytes object in python?

Tags: python, string, object, byte

```
x=bytes("Hello! Welcome to Python")
```

In the above line of code, a string object is being converted into bytes object. But how is that useful as the string object would be finally stored in memory (in binary form) by following some encoding (ASCII or unicode) even if it is not converted into bytes object?

Comment: Usually, bytes are used as input for I/O. Networking or disk. For example, if you want to upload a file to an HTTP API, you can send a request with a filename but the payload can come directly from your program's memory, such as a plain string. The payload will be accepted as the "file" on the other end. That's how we test our API that accepts a file.

Answer (score 0):

When working with empty strings or ASCII strings of one character Python uses string interning. Interned strings act as singletons, that is, if you have two identical strings that are interned, there is only one copy of them in the memory.

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> b = 'world'
>>> a[4],b[1]
('o', 'o')
>>> id(a[4]), id(b[1]), a[4] is b[1]
(4567926352, 4567926352, True)
>>> id('')
4545673904
>>> id('')
4545673904
```

As you can see, both string slices point to the same address in the memory. It's possible because Python strings are immutable.

In Python, string interning is not limed to characters or empty strings. Strings that are created during code compilation can also be interned if their length does not exceed 20 characters.

This includes:

1. function and class names
2. variable names
3. argument names
4. constants (all strings that are defined in the code)
5. keys of dictionaries
6. names of attributes

When you hit enter in Python REPL, your statement gets compiled down to the bytecode. That's why all short strings in REPL are also interned.

```
>>> a = 'teststring'
>>> b = 'teststring'
>>> id(a), id(b), a is b
(4569487216, 4569487216, True)
>>> a = 'test'*5
>>> b = 'test'*5
>>> len(a), id(a), id(b), a is b
(20, 4569499232, 4569499232, True)
>>> a = 'test'*6
>>> b = 'test'*6
>>> len(a), id(a), id(b), a is b
(24, 4569479328, 4569479168, False)
```

This example will not work, because such strings are not constants:

```
>>> open('test.txt','w').write('hello')
5
>>> open('test.txt','r').read()
'hello'
>>> a = open('test.txt','r').read()
>>> b = open('test.txt','r').read()
>>> id(a), id(b), a is b
(4384934576, 4384934688, False)
>>> len(a), id(a), id(b), a is b
(5, 4384934576, 4384934688, False)
```

String interning technique saves tens of thousands of duplicate string allocations. Internally, string interning is maintained by a global dictionary where strings are used as keys. To check if there is already an identical string in the memory Python performs dictionary membership operation.

The unicode object is almost 16 000 lines of C code, so there are a lot of small optimizations which are not mentioned in this article. If you want to learn more about Unicode in Python, I would recommend you to read PEPs about strings and check the code of the unicode object.

Inter conversions are as usual quite popular, but conversion between a string to bytes is more common these days due to the fact that for handling files or Machine Learning ( Pickle File ), we extensively require the strings to be converted to bytes. Let’s discuss certain ways in which this can be performed.

A byte object is a sequence of bytes. These byte objects are machine-readable and can be directly stored on the disk. Strings, on the other hand, are in human-readable form and need to be encoded so that they can be stored on a disk